# Верхний левый пиксель transparent

Tags: css

Добрый день.

Можно ли сделать, чтоб верхний левый пиксель в картинке запомнить как transparent и применить это свойство ко всей картинке?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду, однако есть такое свойство, как `opacity`.

Кроссбраузерное решение выглядит так:

```
.transparent_class {
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: У меня есть смайлики в формате gif и вокруг него белый фон, хочу его убрать.

Comment: В таком случае, то, что вы хотите сделать, не возможно.